# Using cancan the proper way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a certain requirement where the views have different content based upon the type of user. Lets say I have the index action for the users controller. Then I can use cancan to authorize the action like this

```
authorize! :index, @users
```

Further for filtering the content I have another authorization like

`if can :view_all,User`

Further another authorization like

`if can :view_some,User` will require another one.

This will result in lots of conditions. Instead of this, I could have used just simple conditions like

```
If the user is with view_all access show him all 
else if the user is with view_some access show him some
else access denied
```

Cancan requires one extra query, isn't it? I might be using cancan the wrong way. So need some suggestions.

Here is the rough snippet of my ability.rb file

```
    can :index, User do |user1|
      role.accesses.include?(Access.where(:name => "access1").first) || role.accesses.include?(Access.where(:name => "access2").first)
    end

    can :view_all, User do |user1|
      role.accesses.include?(Access.where(:name => "access1").first) 
    end

    can :view_some, User do |user1|
      role.accesses.include?(Access.where(:name => "access2").first) 
    end
```

Comment: Could you show us your ability.rb?

Comment: please mark other questions you've had as answered.

Answer (score 0):

> Cancan requires one extra query?

When combining abilities, cancan will use a single query.

If you look at the specs, eg. `spec/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter_spec.rb`, you'll find specs like this:

```
it "should fetch any articles which are published or secret", focus: true do
  @ability.can :read, Article, :published => true
  @ability.can :read, Article, :secret => true
  article1 = Article.create!(:published => true, :secret => false)
  article2 = Article.create!(:published => true, :secret => true)
  article3 = Article.create!(:published => false, :secret => true)
  article4 = Article.create!(:published => false, :secret => false)
  Article.accessible_by(@ability).should == [article1, article2, article3]
end
```

And if you turn on SQL logging, you'll see that the query combines the conditions:

```
Article Load (0.2ms)  
SELECT "with_model_articles_95131".* 
FROM "with_model_articles_95131" 
WHERE (("with_model_articles_95131"."secret" = 't') 
  OR ("with_model_articles_95131"."published" = 't'))
```